# Using the same data-activates twice

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I have 2 navs in my home_header.blade.php, one for desktop/laptop screens, and one for mobile screens.

```
<div class="home-header">
<nav id="mobile-nav" class="fixed-nav hide-on-med-and-up">
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="brand-logo center grey-text text-darken-2 hide-on-med-and-up">{{ Html::image('images/test-lettermark@3x.png', 'test') }}</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="brand-logo center grey-text text-darken-2 hide-on-small-and-down">{{ Html::image('images/test@3x.png', 'test') }}</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>.

    @include('web.includes.sidebar')
</div>
</nav>
<nav class="nav-extended hide-on-small-and-down" style="border-bottom-width: 0px">
<div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="brand-logo center grey-text text-darken-2 hide-on-med-and-up">{{ Html::image('images/test-lettermark@3x.png', 'test') }}</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="brand-logo center grey-text text-darken-2 hide-on-small-and-down">{{ Html::image('images/test@3x.png', 'test') }}</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

    @include('web.includes.sidebar')
</div>
```

As you can see, both navs uses the same id for data-activates. For some reason, only one of the nav can activate the sidebar, while the other doesn't work.

It is important for me that both nav uses the SAME FILE for the sidebar. Would appreciate if anyone has an idea how to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Without the JS or a demo we can't help.

Comment: Why all the duplication and not just adjust classes based on window size?